# New Warning appearing: include(): Filename cannot be empty when I changed WordPress theme on PHP file to call Advanced Custom Fields admin style

Tags: php, wordpress

I just switched to a new theme and now getting a warning.  I had a PHP file to call some styling for the admin area side of Advanced Custom Fields to make it easier to read.  It always worked in the older theme.

***The warning says:  include(): Filename cannot be empty***

Here's the code that worked fine before, probably just needs to be updated somewhat:

```
function admin_styles() {
    ob_start();
    include( locate_template('templates/admin-styles.php') );
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    echo $output;
}

add_action( 'admin_head' , 'admin_styles');
add_action( 'customize_controls_print_styles' , 'admin_styles');
```

I was doing some research and maybe I should now be using either file_exists or get_template_directory()
Thank you!

Comment: `locate_template` returned empty here, because it didn’t find any template by that given path. Does your new theme contain this template …?

Comment: Opps yep ya got me... the 'ole missing template thing!!  All solved now!!  Long day ;-)  ** The template was indeed missing!  I thought it was there but I was wrong; this is solved, thank you!